# Posting data using jQuery $.post() to controller, cant get post values in controller CodeIgniter

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, codeigniter-2

I am posting to my controller using jQuery $.post() shown below:

```
var data = {

    user_id : $('#users-area [data-toggle="dropdown"]').attr('data-id'),
    message : $('[data-form="send_notification"] [data-input="message-textarea"]:last').val()

};

console.log(data.user_id);
console.log(data.message);

$.post(URL+'notifications/send_notification', data, function(e){

    if(e.status){

            $('body').append('<div class="success_box"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span><p>Notification sent</p></div>');
            $('.success_box').delay(1200).fadeOut();
            window.location = window.location.href;

        } else {

                //alert('Uh oh! Something went wrong, please try again..');

        }

});
```

In my controller I simply have:

```
public function send_notification(){

    //die('msg: '.$this->input->post('message'));
    die('uid: '.$this->input->post('user_id'));

}
```

This is the code for the form:

```
<div id="send_message" class="lightbox">

<h3>Send Notification</h3>

<?php echo form_open('notifications/send_notification', 'data-form="send_notification"'); ?>

    <label for="to-user">To </label>
    <div id="users-area" class="btn-group dropdown"><button data-users="users" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Select a user</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span><span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span></button>
        <ul data-dropper="user-dropdown" id="user-drop" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a data-id="0" href="#">All Users</a></li>
        </ul></div>
    <br>
    <label for="message">Message </label><br>
    <textarea value="" data-input="message-textarea" id="message"></textarea>
    <br>
    <p><?php echo form_submit('', 'Send', 'class="btn btn-primary"'); ?></p>

        <?php echo form_close(); ?>

</form>
```

The result is I get no value for either message or user_id... nothing at all..

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I hadn't returned false after the forms $.post() function in jQuery, this caused the form to be pushed so the page was refreshed, hence no post values after the refresh. See below:

```
var data = {

    user_id : $('#users-area [data-toggle="dropdown"]').attr('data-id'),
    message : $('[data-form="send_notification"] [data-input="message-textarea"]:last').val()
```

};

```
console.log(data.user_id);
console.log(data.message);

$.post(URL+'notifications/send_notification', data, function(e){

    if(e.status){

        $('body').append('<div class="success_box"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span><p>Notification sent</p></div>');
        $('.success_box').delay(1200).fadeOut();
        window.location = window.location.href;

    } else {

        //alert('Uh oh! Something went wrong, please try again..');

    }
});
return false;
```

Thanks!